# How can I make the code print 1234 2341 3412 4123 while using the map container

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc library

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int num;
    int *map;
    int i;

    r = 4;
    c = 4;
    i = 0;
    map = malloc((r * c) * (sizeof(int)));
    num = 1;
    while (map[i] < r * c)
    {
        ft_putchar(num + '0');
        ft_putchar(' ');
        num++;
        if (num == 5)
        {
            ft_putchar('\n');
            num = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    free(map);
    return (0);
}
```

I got the code to output

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

in a 4x4 format but I need help to make it

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 1 
3 4 1 2 
4 1 2 3
```

in a 4x4 format.

I'm sorry if this looks silly but I'm really new to coding, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this code supposed to do anything useful?  You never write to `map[]` and `map[i] < r * c` just test uninitialised memory.

Comment: It's a part of creating a mini Sudoku game, any comments are appreciated!

Comment: You have missed my point.  The result of `map[i] < r * c j` is non-deterministic, and may or may not run for four lines - in my test it output 4.5 lines one time, and 2 a second time. It may overrun the bounds of the allocated memory with further undefined behaviour.  You may have "simplified" your code to ask the question, but it is a good idea not to introduce further bugs in the process - that is just a distraction.

Comment: Be aware that this is only 1 of many ways of filling a valid Sudoku grid.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to rotate elements in an array left one position at a time, and then do that `n-1` times for `n` being the length of the array.

```
 --------------v
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
     <-- <-- <--
```

This individual rotation broken out into a very straightforward function.

```
void rotate_left1(int *arr, size_t n) {
    int first = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        arr[i-1] = arr[i];
    } 
    arr[n-1] = first;
}
```

In your code, please note that C does allow for variable length arrays, and your `map` lives in `main` so there is no need to dynamically allocate it unless you scale it to a point where it will not be able to live on the stack.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there a good way to incorporate this mechanism into the code itself without using a new function? How can I rotate the elements inside the while loop, I tried multiple ways but the map container is limiting.

Comment: Can' do all of your homework for you. :) Programming is about taking big problems and breaking them down into small problems. You can make 4 arrays `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. Now, you can rotate each array a certain number of times.

Comment: Thank you again! I will try and build upon this hint, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The question suggests only that the presentation should rotate, there is no suggestion that these values are stored in an array that may be rotated.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to avoid the undefined behaviour in the loop condition you are not asking about in order that it will in fact run in my test:

This will rotate the sequence `1 2 3 4` on each output line.

```
int r = 4;
int c = 4;
int* map = malloc((r * c) * (sizeof(*map)));
int start = 0 ;
int num = start ;

for( int i = 0; i < r * c; i++ )
{
    ft_putchar( num + '1');
    ft_putchar(' ');
    num = (num + 1) % 4 ;
    if( num == start)
    {
        ft_putchar('\n');
        start = (start + 1) % 4 ;
        num = start ;
    }
}
free(map);
```

I have removed the separate instantiation/initialisation nonsense you had - don't do that.

The solution increments the start value on each iteration and uses modulo-4 arithmetic to wrap from 3 to zero.  The output is `+ '1'` rather then `+ '0'` because arithmetically it is easier to use 0 to 3 rather then 1 to 4 (it allows the use of the `%` modulo operator).

Answer (score 0):

The original code wasn't making use of the `map` array so I modified it to first populate `map` then just print what's in the array.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc library

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int main(void)
  {
  int rows = 4;
  int cols = 4;
  char *map;

  map = malloc((rows * cols) * (sizeof(char)));

  for(int r = 0 ; r < rows ; ++r)
    for(int c = 0 ; c < cols ; ++c)
      map[(r * cols) + c] = '0' + ((r + c) % cols) + 1;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < (rows * cols) ; ++i)
    {
    ft_putchar(map[i]);
    if(i % cols == (cols - 1))
      ft_putchar('\n');
    }

  free(map);
  return 0;
  }
```

Of course, there really isn't a need for `map`, and getting rid of it makes the code that much simpler:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc library

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int main(void)
  {
  int rows = 4;
  int cols = 4;

  for(int r = 0 ; r < rows ; ++r)
    for(int c = 0 ; c < cols ; ++c)
      {
      ft_putchar('0' + ((r + c) % cols) + 1);

      if(((r * cols) + c) % cols == (cols - 1))
        ft_putchar('\n');
      }

  return 0;
  }
```